# Python extract value from multiple substring

Tags: python, lambda, substring, extract

I have a dataframe named df which has a column named "text" consisting of each row which a string like this: This is the string of the MARC data format.

```
d20s 22 i2as¶001VNINDEA455133910000005¶008180529c 1996 frmmm wz 7b ¶009se z 1 m mm c¶008a ¶008at ¶008ap ¶008a ¶0441 $a2609-2565$c2609-2565¶0410 $afre$aeng$apor ¶0569 $a2758-8965$c4578-7854¶0300 $a789$987$754 ¶051 $atxt$asti$atdi$bc¶110 $317737535$w20..b.....$astock market situation¶3330 $aimport and export agency ABC¶7146 $q1$uwwww.abc.org$ma1¶7146 $q9$uAgency XYZ¶8799 $q1$uAgency ABC$fHTML$
```

Here I want to extract information containing in zones ¶7146, after $u or zone ¶0441, after $c.

The result table will be like this :

| ¶7146$u | ¶0441$c |
| --- | --- |
| wwww.abc.org | 2609-2565 |
| Agency XYZ | 2609-2565 |

Here is the code I made :

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests


df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

def extract(text, start_pattern, sc):
    ist = text.find(start_pattern)
    if ist < 0:
        return ""
    ist = text.find(sc, ist)
    if ist < 0:
        return ""
    im = text.find("$", ist + len(sc))
    iz = text.find("¶", ist + len(sc))
    if im >= 0:
        if iz >= 0:
            ie = min(im, iz)
        else:
            ie = im
    else:
        ie = iz
    if ie < 0:
        return ""
    return text[ist + len(sc): ie]

def extract_text(row, list_in_zones):
    text = row["text"]
    if pd.isna(text):
        return [""] * len(list_in_zones)
    patterns = [("¶" + p, "$" + c) for p, c in [zone.split("$") for zone in list_in_zones]]
    return [extract(text, pattern, sc) for pattern, sc in patterns]


list_in_zones = ["7146$u", "0441$u", "200$y"]


df[list_in_zones] = df.apply(lambda row: extract_text(row, list_in_zones),
                             axis=1,
                             result_type="expand")

df.to_excel("extract.xlsx", index = False)
```

For zones ¶7146 and after $u, my code only extracted "www.abc.org", he cannot extract the duplicate with value "Agency XYZ". What's wrong here?.

Additional logical structure : The logic about the structure of the string is that each zone will start with a character ¶ like ¶7146, ¶0441,.. , and the fields start with $ for example $u, $c and this field ends with either $ or ¶. Here, I want to extract information in the fields $.

Comment: This data is very stange to me but..   ¶7146 $q9$u  -  does each section always begin with  ¶  and end with $[a..z]?

Comment: @Lewis Morris : Yes. Each section always begin with ¶ but end with $ or ¶

Comment: This is the string of the MARC data format.

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting and then cleaning up strings as follows

```
import pandas as pd
text = ('d20s 22 i2as¶001VNINDEA455133910000005¶008180529c 1996 frmmm wz 7b ¶009se z 1 m mm c¶008a ¶008at ¶008ap ¶008a ¶0441 $a2609-2565$c2609-2565¶0410 $afre$aeng$apor ¶0569 $a2758-8965$c4578-7854¶0300 $a789$987$754 ¶051 $atxt$asti$atdi$bc¶110 $317737535$w20..b.....$astock market situation¶3330 $aimport and export agency ABC¶7146 $q1$uwwww.abc.org$ma1¶7146 $q9$uAgency XYZ¶8799 $q1$uAgency ABC$fHTML$')
u = text.split('$u')[1:3] # Taking just the seconds and third elements in the array because they match your desired output
c = text.split('$c')[1:3]

pd.DataFrame([u,c]).T
```

OUTPUT

```
    0   1
0   wwww.abc.org$ma1¶7146 $q9   2609-2565¶0410 $afre$aeng$apor ¶0569 $a2758-8965
1   Agency XYZ¶8799 $q1 4578-7854¶0300 $a789$987$754 ¶051 $atxt$asti$a...
```

From here you can try to clean up the strings until they match the desired output.

It would be easier to give a more helpful answer if we could understand the logic behind this data structure - when do certain fields start and end?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you be a little more specific? The logic about the structure of the string is that each zone will start with a character, ¶ and the fields start with $ for example $u, $c and this field ends with either $ or ¶.

Comment: This is the string of the MARC data format.